# How to find the exponential base

Tags: exponential-function

I saw this question asking $x^{0.25} = 2.5045$

One of the answers rewrote is as $x^b=a$

And then they said to divide both sides by $\frac{1}{b}$, thats what im confused on, why must you divide both sides by $\frac{1}{b}$

Answer (score 0):

You could say $$x^{0.25} = 2.5045$$ is equivalent to $$0.25 \log(x) = \log(2.5045)$$ and then divide both sides by $0.25$, i.e. multiply both sides by $\frac1{0.25}=4$, to give $$\log(x) = 4\log(2.5045)$$ which is equivalent to  $$x = 2.5045^4$$ which you can calculate.